# PDE wave equation can't factor

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the general solution $u_{xx} + u_{xt} - 10u_{tt} = 0$

In general, when we face wave equation like this type we can factor and easily find the general solution of the form $u(x,t) = f(x + ct) + g(x - ct)$. But the point is this equation can't factor perfectly, how should I start an approach？

Comment: Rewrite the PDE as $$\begin{pmatrix} \partial_x & \partial_y\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & -10\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \partial_x \\ \partial_y \end{pmatrix}u = 0.$$Diagonalize this coefficient matrix to get a change of variables that will put this into the form $au_{\xi\xi} - bu_{\eta \eta} = 0$ with $a,b>0$. It does not look pretty.

Comment: How did you obtain this matrix. Anyways, is there any easier way to do it. This looks complicated to me.

Comment: In this cases, the solution is better $u(x,t) = f(x - c_1t) + g(x - c_2t)$ being $1/c_1$ and $1/c_2$, in this problem,, the roots of the equation $c^2+c-10=0$.